# Como instalar e utilizar Bootstrap via Composer

Tags: php, composer

Olá, Pessoal como posso utilizar o **Bootstrap** em um projeto gerenciado pelo Composer, eu sei que se realizar o comando **composer require twbs/bootstrap** o composer irá baixar e colocar o os arquivos na pasta **vendor** do projeto, como faço para adicionar os código nas páginas.

```
<link href="./vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/bootstrap.css">
```

Obedecendo a seguinte estrutura do projeto:

```
projeto/
---logs/
---public/
---src/
---template/
---tests/
---vendor/
---composer.json
---composer.lock
```

Isso seria o correto a fazer?

Eu acredito que isso não é o mais aconselhável, será que existe algo que possa fazer para que adicione diretamente? Ex: `<link href="./public/assets/bootstrap.css">`

Comment: Composer, apesar de ter suporte a isso, não foi feito para isso. Utilize outros como `yarn`, `npm` etc. Mas caso queira, tem um link que pode ajudar: https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/how-do-i-install-a-package-to-a-custom-path-for-my-framework.md

Comment: Olha não sou mto bom com esse **composer** e não consegui configurar como monstra no link que vc mandou... segue meu link arquivo _composer.json_ `{
 "require": {
  "composer/installers": "~1.0",
  "php": ">=5.5.0",
  "slim/slim": "^3.1",
  "slim/php-view": "^2.0",
  "monolog/monolog": "^1.17",
  "twbs/bootstrap": "3.3.7"
 },
 "extra": {
  "installer-paths": {
   "public/assets/{$name}": ["vendor/package"]
  }
 },
 "require-dev": {
  "phpunit/phpunit": ">=4.8 < 6.0"
 },
 "autoload-dev": {
  "psr-4": {
   "Tests\\": "tests/"
  }
 }
}
`

Answer (score 0):

Não é o melhor modo, mas da pra fazer apenas importando no projeto pelo composer.json:

```
{
   "name": "projeto/projeto",
   "description": "descricao.",
   "authors": [
      {
         "name": "nome",
         "email": "email@email.com"
      }
   ],
   "require": {
      "components/jquery": "^3.2",
      "twbs/bootstrap": "4.0.0"
   }
}
```

Ou pelo terminal:

> composer require components/jquery
>
> composer require twbs/bootstrap

E depois inclua os arquivos que estão em `/vendor`:

```
<link href="vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="vendor/components/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**Obs:**

O Bootstrap 4 vai pedir para que seja incluido o auxiliar [Tether.io](http://tether.io/), basta incluir seu caminho CDN **ANTES** do arquivo JavaScript do bootstrap, ficando esses arquivos necessários.

```
<link href="vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="vendor/components/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.3/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**Obs 2:**

Se o arquivo inicial (index) estiver em public, onde vai o caminho para o arquivo indique para voltar uma pasta antes do informar o caminho completo:

> ../vendor/caminho/para/o/arquivo.formato

Comment: onde o bootstrap solicita o auxiliar Tether.io ?